# Disk Usage in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, disk, du, linux-disk-free

I am trying to debug the storage usage in my kubernetes pod. I have seen the pod is evicted because of Disk Pressure.  When i login to running pod, the see the following

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          30G   21G  8.8G  70% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs            14G     0   14G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        30G   21G  8.8G  70% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            14G   12K   14G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs            14G     0   14G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs            14G     0   14G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs            14G     0   14G   0% /sys/firmware
root@deploy-9f45856c7-wx9hj:/# du -sh /
du: cannot access '/proc/1142/task/1142/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1142/task/1142/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1142/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1142/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
227M    /
root@deploy-9f45856c7-wx9hj:/# du -sh /tmp
11M /tmp
root@deploy-9f45856c7-wx9hj:/# du -sh /dev
0   /dev
root@deploy-9f45856c7-wx9hj:/# du -sh /sys
0   /sys
root@deploy-9f45856c7-wx9hj:/# du -sh /etc
1.5M    /etc
root@deploy-9f45856c7-wx9hj:/#
```

As we can see 21G is consumed, but when i try to run `du -sh` it just returns 227M. I would like to find out who(which directory) is consuming the space

Comment: Hi, can you run the command with `du -ash` , it will show hidden directory. hopefully, there is no snapshot happening in the pod

Comment: please add more information about the df result, like where the command was performed? which mount is your docker using?

Comment: also share your kubelet data for eviction hard and soft threshold

Comment: 1. Old pod was evicted by DiskPressure, it maybe not because of the old pod's size, checking all the pod on the node.  2. The running pod is new created, so let it running and check the size later.

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs [Node Conditions](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/master/content/en/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource.md#node-conditions), `DiskPressure` has to do with conditions on the node causing kubelet to evict the pod. It doesn't necessarily mean it's the pod that caused the conditions.

> DiskPressure
>
> Available disk space and inodes on either the node’s root filesystem
>   or image filesystem has satisfied an eviction threshold

You may want to investigate what's happening on the node instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the process `1142` is still running and holding file descriptors and/or perhaps some space (You may have other processes and other file descriptors too not being released) Is it the [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/)?. To alleviate the problem you can verify that it's running and then kill it:

```
$ ps -Af | grep 1142
$ kill -9 1142
```

P.D. You need to provide more information about the processes and what's running on that node.

Comment: Its a kubernetes pod